# How can I figure out of a device is connected to the internet from my server?

Tags: node.js

I need a presence system for my application. I need to display if they're "online" or "offline" based on whether they're able to communicate with the server or not. Firebase seems to have [had a solution to this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html), but the Firebase realtime database costs money to use, which we're not interested in since it's just a school project we're finishing up. Are there any other solutions for Node.js and Android for a system like this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use websockets and socket.io for this.

It is simple to send a notification to all clients when one of them gets disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

If the "online" state is not time critical, you could just `ping` your clients in a given interval.
Either using the systems `ping` command or a npm module which provides a wrapper for this.